# Are extradited prisoners residents of the receiving country?

Tags: extradition, immigration

I'm interested in answers for various jurisdictions.

If a person of country A is extradited to country B, are they considered to be residents of country B while they are serving their sentence?

Notice that I'm asking about residence, not citizenship. Of course you don't get to become a citizen of a different country by being imprisoned in it.

In practical terms:

- Does the prisoner need to get a passport from country A to leave their country? (Do they get an exit stamp?)
- Does the prisoner need a long term resident "prisoner" visa, or something like that?
- Does the prisoner need to register as a resident when they arrive? Presumably with the prison address as their residential address?
- Does the prisoner need to pay taxes, get social security, etc. of country B?
- Does the time served count, for example, when applying for permanent residence or naturalization, when applicable?

In other words, for immigration purposes, what is the status of a person who got into the country via extradition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

> Does the prisoner need a long term resident "prisoner" visa, or something like that?

No, during detention a residence permit is not required.

> Does the prisoner need to register as a resident when they arrive? Presumably with the prison address as their residential address?

When the expected period of detention exceeds 3 months and no residence exists in Germany, then the prisoner will be reported to the registration authority.

> Does the time served count, for example, when applying for permanent residence or naturalization, when applicable?

If no residence permit existed, then the time does not count.

> In other words, for immigration purposes, what is the status of a person who got into the country via extradition?

If they had no immigration status when the detention started, they will have no status when it ends.

---

> [Ausländerrechtliches Stichwortverzeichnis - Freiabonnements für Gefangene e.V.](https://freiabos.de/auslaenderrechtliches-stichwortverzeichnis/#titelin)
> **Aufenthaltstitel in Haft**
> Ausländische Gefangene benötigen für die Zeit der Haft keinen Aufenthaltstitel. Läuft aber zum Beispiel die Aufenthaltserlaubnis während der (Untersuchungs-)Haft ab, muss unbedingt fristgerecht ein neuer Antrag gestellt werden.
>
> > **Residence permit in detention**
> > **Foreign prisoners do not need a residence permit for the period of detention**.  However, if, for example, the residence permit expires during (pre-trial) detention, a new application must be submitted in good time.
>
> ...
> **Ausländerrechtliche Folgen einer Verurteilung**
> ...
> Besteht kein Aufenthaltstitel, ist der Ausländer **nach Beendigung der Untersuchungs- bzw. Strafhaft von Gesetzes wegen zur Ausreise verpflichtet**.
>
> > **Immigration law consequences of a conviction**
> > ...
> > If there is no residence permit, the foreigner **is legally obliged to leave the country after the end of the pre-trial or criminal detention**.

---

> [Vollzugsgeschäftsordnung Vom 21. Dezember 2018 JustVA (Berlin)](https://www.berlin.de/justizvollzug/_assets/senjustv/gesetze/verwaltungsvorschriften/vgo_berlin_vom_21.12.2018.pdf) (PDF)
>
> - Page 22 of PDF
>
> **24 Mitteilung der Aufnahme an die Meldebehörde**
> (1) Die Aufnahme von Gefangenen zum Vollzug einer Freiheitsentziehung **ist innerhalb von zwei Wochen der Meldebehörde mitzuteilen, wenn die Gefangenen nach ihren Angaben nicht für eine Wohnung im Inland gemeldet sind und der Aufenthalt in der Anstalt drei Monate übersteigt**. Übersteigt der Aufenthalt in der Anstalt bei der Aufnahme zunächst nicht drei Monate oder ist die Dauer der Freiheitsentziehung bei Aufnahme, wie beispielsweise beim Vollzug der Untersuchungshaft, nicht bekannt, tritt eine Mitteilungspflicht erst dann ein, wenn durch sich anschließende oder fortdauernde Freiheitsentziehung die Dauer von drei Monaten überschritten wird; die Mitteilung hat sodann innerhalb von zwei Wochen zu erfolgen.
>
> > **24 Notification of admission to the registration authority**
> > (1) The admission of prisoners for the execution of a deprivation of liberty shall be **reported to the registration authority within two weeks if the prisoners say they are not registered for an apartment in Germany and the stay in the institution exceeds three months**.  If the stay in the institution does not initially exceed three months at the time of admission or if the duration of the deprivation of liberty is not known at the time of admission, e.g. in the case of remand detention, a notification obligation only arises if subsequent or ongoing deprivation of liberty exceeds the period of three months  months is exceeded;  the notification must then be made within two weeks.

Answer (score 1):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

Being a prisoner does not make one a citizen.  Practically, an extradited citizen of another country would almost certainly be deported after their sentence was completed.

As such, the prisoner:

- does not get a passport
- does not need a visa.  They are in the US as a ward of the government.
- does not need to register as a resident.
- does not pay taxes nor qualify for social security or other social programs apart form those administered by the penal system
- does not really get to stay, I doubt residency requirements even matter.  Countries do not naturalize convicts except in exceptional cases.  In the US, there is a moral character component which a convict will have trouble passing, and some crimes are automatic denials to citizenship. Even if not automatically barred from emigrating, there are time requirements post-incarceration. A typical result after incarceration of a foreign national is detention in an immigration facility.

Comment: This all makes sense, but it would be great if you had some sources on this information.

Answer (score 1):

Country B might be trying to get one of their own citizens, currently in country A on whatever legal permission or lack of permission, extradited *back* to stand trial in B. I guess you are not interested in that.

Country B might be trying to get a resident or citizen of A extradited to stand trial in B. There will be documentation of the request, by both documents, and the suspect or his or her lawyer will also get plenty of paperwork to document leaving A and going to B. The suspect may not have a passport, and certainly does not have custody of his or her passport, so entry and exit stamps are a bit pointless.

Once in B, there is usually a difference between a legally acknowledged presence ("the inmate is currenty residing in such-and-such prison") and various levels of residency permit. B should inform the suspect's lawyers and the consular service of his or her home country, at least. Most countries have rules how inmates are counted for census purposes, but with a reasonable rule-of-law and administrative system, no inmate *should* simply disappear from the files.

If the trial leads to acquittal or if the sentence is served, and if there are no other extradition requests pending, the ex-inmate is in B and outside prison. He or she would usually be served with deportation papers, and the usual process begins. The ex-inmate could be stateless, could try and make an asylum claim, etc.

Comment: Especially if the court case ends with acquittal because the person is innocent, wouldn’t B have the duty to get them back home?

Comment: @gnasher729, he question seemed to imply a suspect who does not want to go home.

Answer (score 1):

The situation is just complicated. Country B may be prepared and have specific laws for this situation or they might not. Countries most likely have laws following common sense, or in the absence of specific laws act in a way following common sense.

Let’s take a complex example: A German citizen, UK resident with pre-settled status in the UK on a 10 week US holiday, accused (and guilty) of a crime either in the UK or in Germany, and getting extradited to that country. You can see this will be complicated.

You won’t need a passport and/or visa to enter the country, go to court, and go to jail. After all, you are “invited” by the country. This will most likely not affect your residency status. Becoming a convicted criminal is quite likely to affect you, but it would depend on the severity of the crime. And in the case of Uk settled status, absence from the UK over 6 months would affect your ability to change pre-settled to settled status.